# React, testing for input placeholder

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have this html input:

```
<input
  id='palapa'
  className='amount'
  placeholder={props.placeholder}
  type='number'
/>
```

I know it needs a `value` and a `onChange` event, but right now I want to test the value of the placeholder, in other words, I will be checking if some certain `props` is being rendered.

I was trying this without succes:

```
const defaultProps = {
    options: [
      { value: 'CLP', label: 'CLP' },
      { value: 'USD', label: 'USD' }
    ],
    placeholder: 'thePlaceHolder',
    topMessage: 'topMessage'
};

//<CurrencyInput > returns the input from above

const rendered = render(<CurrencyInput {...defaultProps} />);
const input = rendered.getByLabelText('palapa');
console.log(input); // undefined, I'm trying to get here "thePlaceHolder"
```

Any hiny?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach,

```
 const defaultProps = {
      options: [
        { value: 'CLP', label: 'CLP' },
        { value: 'USD', label: 'USD' }
      ],
      placeholder: 'thePlaceHolder',
      topMessage: 'topMessage'
    };
    const {container} = render(<CurrencyInput {...defaultProps} />);
    const input = container.querySelector('#palapa');
    console.log(input.placeholder); // thePlaceHolder
    expect(input.placeholder).toBe('thePlaceHolder');

   --------------[or]----------------

  const rendered = render(<CurrencyInput {...defaultProps} />);
  const input = rendered.getByPlaceholderText('thePlaceHolder');
  console.log(input); //thePlaceHolder
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `const input = rendered.getByPlaceholderText('palapa');` (see https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries/#byplaceholdertext)

`getByLabelText` will work if your `input` is wrapped/associated with a `label`